# Получение спектра для распознавания речи

Tags: javascript, c++, распознавание-речи

Как я понял, для того, чтобы работать со звуком, нужно разложить его на спектр, используя ряд Фурье.
Допустим у меня есть какой то звуковой файл(mp3 или wav). Как мне оттуда вытащить данные, чтобы разложить на спектр, используя преобразование фурье? Или этот процесс делается как то иначе? И какие библиотеки нужно использовать для этого(с++ или Js) именно для получения сырых данных. Я знаю, есть готовые библиотеки для разложение в ряд, но мне интересен сам процесс

Comment: Читал я на Википедии, что такое [Ряд_Фурье](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ряд_Фурье) Если вникните в формулы, которые там представлены, то сможете разложить на спектр без библиотек. Я и сам задавался этим вопросом, но всегда не хватало времени. А вот в файлах обычного формата WAV звуковые данные хранятся в несжатом и незашифрованном виде, их можно извлечь без специальных функций и на многих языках.

Answer (score 0):

Вы уже сегодня спрашивали [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/798995/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-audio-%D0%B2-js/799052#799052), в моём коде там есть такие строки:

```js
data_L = buffer.getChannelData(0);
data_R = buffer.getChannelData(1);
```

Это и есть одномерные массивы с полученными сырыми данными для левого и правого звуковых каналов. Эти данные ещё называют семплами. А вот разложить звуковой файл на спектр поможет функция [BaseAudioContext.createAnalyser()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createAnalyser)