# Как можно сделать волну для mp3 файла?

Tags: javascript, html, аудио, ui

Есть подобный рисунок, я плохо понимаю как вообще можно генерировать с помощью js волны зависящие от громкости в конкретный момент, была пара статеек как сделать полосками, но как можно сделать волны? буду благодарен если поможете

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [тыц](https://www.bbc.co.uk/rd/blog/2013-10-audio-waveforms) - очень прям полезная ссылка для вас :-)

Comment: Это обсуждалось тут: [Получение сырых данных Audio в js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/798995/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-audio-%D0%B2-js/799052#799052)

Comment: @Олег я отмеченный вариант пытаюсь запустить, он у меня не врубается... хз чего так

Comment: Не рисует график,даже на пустом html

Comment: Какой именно вариант, где он отмечен?

Comment: @Олег который с репутацией 4) вроде на нескольких ресурсах проверил, не получилось

Comment: Но какой вариант из двух? Там по моей ссылке есть на канвасе и на программно созданном файле БМП.

Comment: именно такую нет времени но что нибудь подобное могу реализовать с помощью плагина если захотите .

Comment: Если первый вариант с канвасом, то этот скрипт с момента публикации оказывается перестал поддерживать ссылку на МП3-файл в другом домене. Я поместил МП3-файл в один каталог с HTML-файлом, и всё стало на места. Вот [ссылка](http://opan1.16mb.com/stackoverflow/wavemp3/index.html) - рисует!

Comment: @Олег Я понял, спасибо, ну и если не тайна, как изменить на волны дизайн?  саму концепцию, решение не надо

Comment: Дизайн можно изменить как угодно, это ограничивается лишь возможностями canvas. На пример, на Вашем рисунке используется плавный переход цвета с лева на право. Я сделал такой же эффект по моей ссылке, алгоритм определения цвета можете посмотреть в исходном коде страницы в строках 57 и 60.